# Iterate through values of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

having a dataframe similar to the following

```
Country 00:00 00:30 01:00 ... 23:00 23:30
SWE     10    15    32        12    57
ITA     6     67    64        1     8
USA     92    13    45        8     32
...
```

How can I e.g. loop through the items of USA (and incrementing by 10) while checking if the index is not bigger than 13:30? e.g.

```
for x in df[df.Country == 'USA]:
    if x.index != '13:30':
        x =+ 10
    else:
        break
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: could you post hier an output of `df.head()`, because now it's not clear - you are saying `13:30` is an index element, but in provided sample it looks like a column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Country == 'USA', '00:00':'13:30'] += 10
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works like a charm!